# How to fill an array with all possible combinations of 2 value pairs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wrote some Javascript code to create a very simple card dealer for a homework assignment.
In essence, you click a button to draw 5 cards from an array of 52 cards (in this case it had to be 52 card **objects**), and those 5 cards get displayed like this:

- 7 of Clubs
- 6 of Spades
- 7 of Hearts
- 10 of Spades
- 10 of Spades

The part I can't seem to figure out though is that each card in the array needs to be unique and as you can see in my example which I took from the output of my code, there are duplicates.
I don't quite know how to go about filling the array with 52 unique card objects, i.e every combination of suits and values.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Robo Dealer</h1>

  <button onclick="dealHand();">Deal Hand</button>

  <hr />
  <div id="card_hand"></div>

  <script>
    // Declaring arrays for suits and values
    const suits = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
    const values = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
    // Creating the card object
    class Card {
      constructor(suit, value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
      }
    }

    const deck = [];
    function createDeck() {
      for (i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
          const card = { value: values[j], suit: suits[i] };
          deck.push(card);
        }
      }
      return deck;
    }
    var hand = new Array();
    function getDeck() {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
        hand.push(deck[x]);
      }
      return hand;
    }

    //  Dealing hand of 5 card objects / outputting it to HTML
    const dealHand = () => {
      let callCreateDeck = createDeck();
      let callGetDeck = getDeck();
      let str = "";
      for (i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        let obj = hand[i];
        str += `- ${obj["value"]}  of ${obj["suit"]}  <br>  `;
        $("#card_hand").html(str);
      }

      return false; // prevent page reload
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Additionally, whenever the button is clicked, another set of 5 cards is drawn and I would like to make it so that when the button is clicked while a set of 5 cards is already being displayed, those cards get cleared/ replaced by the new set of cards and you can only draw more cards until there are no more remaining cards.

Comment: btw, is it intentionally not to declare `i` and `j`?

Comment: why not [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) the items and take the first five, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Declaring arrays for suits and values
    const suits = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
    const values = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"];
    // Creating the card object
    class Card {
      constructor(suit, value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
      }
    }

    function createDeck() {
        const deck = []
        for (let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            const card = { value: values[j], suit: suits[i] };
            deck.push(card);
          }
        }
        
        // shuffle the deck
        deck.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        return deck;
    }
    
    const deck = createDeck();

    //  Dealing hand of 5 card objects / outputting it to HTML
    const dealHand = () => {
      let str = "";
      
      for (let i = 0; i < (deck.length < 5 ? deck.length : 5); i++) {
        let obj = deck[i];
        str += `- ${obj.value}  of ${obj.suit}  <br>  `;
        $("#card_hand").html(str);
      }
      
      // remove first five cards
      deck.splice(0, 5)

      return false; // prevent page reload
    };
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Robo Dealer</h1>

  <button onclick="dealHand();">Deal Hand</button>

  <hr />
  <div id="card_hand"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing the drawn card from the deck you are only adding it to your hand.
You can copy your deck each time you draw cards and remove each drawn card from the copy of the deck using the `temporaray_deck.splice(x, 1)` function, which will remove the object at index `x` from the `temporary_deck`. The 2nd parameter just tells it to remove that amount of elements in this case 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).